# SQL adding value to a List with Select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

just started programming in SQL but i cant get my code to work.

I want to add a row with to my table languages, the table languages is having an Country code, name of the language and the percentage of people that speak the language.

I have seen another post that stated i have to add a new value to my list with the following command:

```
INSERT into language
Values(val1, val2, val3, val4)
```

So i want to select the land code for my language by looking into my table named country where i lookup the land code for the country 'Australia' (line 3 of the code below this text). I just enter the name of the language as a string (line 4 of the code below this text) And last I select the amount of people living in Australia by looking at the population in my table named country if name = "Astralia" (line 5 of the code below)

```
insert into language
values(
select Code from country where Name = "Australia",
"Light Warlpir",
select 350 / population  from country where Name = "Australia")
```

I just dont get why my code is not working, is it legal to use a select command into a Insert command in SQL?

- I am using the Open Source Mondial Database

Thanks A lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Subqueries need their own parentheses.  But, in this case, it is better to write the query using `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into language
    select Code, 'Light Warlpir', 350 / population
    from country
    where Name = 'Australia';
```

Note:  you should list the columns for an `insert`, so it should really start like this:

```
insert into language(Code, Name, Percentage)
```

(or whatever the columns are).